# Scaling of parameters for a large order of magnitude 1e-26 to 1e-15?

Tags: physics, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have parameters and they range in different order of magnitude.

```
   T1 = 1e-26;
   T2 = 1e-19;
   T3 = 1e-18;
   T4 = 1e-17;
   T5 = 1e-16;
```

They are calculated at some conditions e.g temperature.

The scaling should be done in a way that the
values are in the range of, 0.1 to 1.5, approximately.

That means putting in the equation, these ranges could provide the relationship of this quantity with reference to the temperature, etc.

For instance, the equation is like that  S = T*1.54/240; where T is the scaled value of the above quantities T1, T2, T3, T4, T5.

How to do scaling so that I get some reasonable scaled value i.e. S?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the logarithm of T or S if you're not worried about small differences between parameters?